# MyFaces 2.1 redirect navigation case

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I just switch from Mojarra to Myfaces. Mostly not too much of a hassle but for the navigation rules not working as before. I'm have problems with redirect in the navigation case:

```
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>test.edit</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/test.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
```

Any command link navigation such as below will result in a 403 error (access denied) :

```
 <h:commandLink value="Add" id="test" action="test.edit"/>
```

In this particular case the browser has attempted to redirect to test.xhtml (not test.jsf). This is prevented by the security constraints in web.xml. Of course if you remove the security constraints you serve the raw xhtml.

If I remove the redirect it works just fine, but of course does not change the browser Url.

Also I used to be able to do navigation on void outcomes like:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/test.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{bean.save}</from-action>
        <if>#{true}</if>
        <to-view-id>/list.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

However when an ajax request is sent to dynamically show a list (not calling the bean.save method) then the page is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems when moving from Mojarra to MyFaces, the best bet is send a mail to MyFaces users mailing list, so if there is a bug there are better chances to get it solved. Try the latest version (at JUN 2011 is 2.0.7 / 2.1.1). See [MyFaces Mailing Lists](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html)

The first one seems to be a bug, but more info related to your web.xml config is required. The second one is expected.

If it is a bug, you can file an issue here [MyFaces Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES)